# Javascript: event.which and charCodeAt working together

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress

I take what the user typed using event.which on a keypress, and output using String.fromCharCode.

User types:  **a**
event.which: **67**
Outputs:     **A**

For numbers and letters I can handle, but when talking about special characters, I get totally different outputs.

User types:  **-**
event.which: **189**
Outputs:     **½**

After a research, I came across the function **charCodeAt**, and using this one, the output comes perfectly, even special characters.

Unfortunately, I can't use charCodeAt because the user types directly from the $(document), and not from a field.

So, the question is, is there a way I can get the right charCode from the keyPress event.which?

If still can't figure out my doubt, I made you a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QCHt7/) =)

Comment: I'm unclear what you meant when you explained why you can't use charCodeAt.

Comment: Because I have to get what the user typed from ANYWHERE on the document, not only inside a field

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `keypress` event instead of `keyup`. It reports character code instead of key codes, and it triggers when actual characters are typed, not when a key is released, so it handles repeated characters too.

```
$('#field').focus().keypress(function(e){
  var key = e.which;
  $("#key").val(String.fromCharCode(key));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/QCHt7/1/

#### Edit:

If you want to catch keypresses everywhere, you have to hook up the event on the document, and also on any elements that consumes keypresses. A textbox for example will handle the keypress and won't let it bubble up to the parent element.

Comment: My page has no elements that consume keypresses, only the document. It's hard to explain, because I am not developing a page, it's a plugin, so I don't know how's the page of the developer who is using my plugin

Comment: Just as a side note, `keypress` generally only detects keys that have a printable representation.  If you want to catch modifier keys, arrow keys, or function keys, you must use `keyup` or `keydown`.

Answer (score 2):

You are using keyup, an event that reports which key was pressed, and not which character was entered. You should use keypress instead, like so:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e){
    console.log(String.fromCharCode(e.which));
});
```

From [jquery doc on keypress](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/):

> Note that keydown and keyup provide a code indicating which key is
>   pressed, while keypress indicates which character was entered. For
>   example, a lowercase "a" will be reported as 65 by keydown and keyup,
>   but as 97 by keypress. An uppercase "A" is reported as 65 by all
>   events. Because of this distinction, when catching special keystrokes
>   such as arrow keys, .keydown() or .keyup() is a better choice.